# GoogleMap throwing null pointer on getMap();

Tags: android, google-maps

I am having a FragmentActivity, where I have successfully implemented a Google Map through my XML with this code:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/googleMap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

However, if I try to initialize the map to find a persons location with this code:

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap))).getMap();
```

It is throwing a null pointer exception, as I have understood from other questions regarding this error, it shouldn't be a problem initializing the map when it is created in the XML file. And yes I have used

```
setContentView(R.layout.map);
```

Before I initialize the map.

Comment: Seperate the map call into multiple lines. Maybe its just the fragment, which is null.

Comment: May be relevant: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMap()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the Support Fragment So in your XML File Add
this Line In Fragment

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

like belove.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/googleMap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 />
```

and Put This

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to incorrect variable initialization try to change your code as shown below,thanks

```
private GoogleMap gMap;
MapFragment googleMap;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_search);
    googleMap= (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.googleMap);
          gMap= googleMap.getMap();
```

Answer (score 1):

In you xml you are using MapFragment.Change it -

```
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

java -

```
 googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment)).getMap();
```